Runtime error pred tensor size is 64 which is different to y_train tensor size , the tensor dim error
I'm trying to use the Hippo model to predict the forex price (the dataset have datetime column and open price column). Here's the GitHub link to the full codes GitHub Repo
The original hippo model can be found at this link: GitHub Model
I have 2 issues:

In the update states u, the second dim should be batch size, which is [64,1], in my case, I set it to 1, but it still shows [1, 64]
The runtime error to pred tensor size is not match y_train size in output20.

Here's the error detail
Cell In[18], line 17, in train(X_train, y_train, model, loss_fn, optimizer, batch_size, device)
     14 print('pred.shpae:',pred.shape)
     15 print('y_train',y_train.shape)
---> 17 loss = loss_fn(pred, torch.tensor(y_train))
     18 optimizer.zero_grad()
     19 loss_backward()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:535, in MSELoss.forward(self, input, target)
    534 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 535     return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3338, in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   3335 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3336     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3338 expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
   3339 return torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:76, in broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
     74 if has_torch_function(tensors):
     75     return handle_torch_function(broadcast_tensors, tensors, *tensors)
---> 76 return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (4322) at non-singleton dimension 0

Here's my "train" method which is throwing an error on loss_fn
def train(X_train, y_train, model, loss_fn, optimizer, batch_size = None, device = None):
    size = len(X_train)
    if device is None:
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    model.to(device)
    if batch_size is None:
#         X_train_tensor= torch.tensor(X_train, dtype = torch.float32).to(device)
#         y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype = torch.float32).to(device)
    

        model.train()
        pred = model(X_train)[0]  
        print('pred.shpae:',pred.shape)
        print('y_train',y_train.shape)
        
        loss = loss_fn(pred, torch.tensor(y_train))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_backward()
        optimizer.step()
        loss_value = loss.item()
        print(f'loss:{loss_value:>7f}, [{size:>5d}/{size:>5d}]')
    else:
        dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(X_train, y_train)
        dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
        
        model.train()
       
        for batch_idx, (X_batch, y_batch )in enumerate(dataloader):
            X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device,dtype = torch.float32), y_batch.to(device,dtype = torch.float32)
        
        # computing prediction error
        pred = model(X_batch)
        loss_ = loss_fn(pred, y_batch)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch%10==0:
            loss_value = loss.item()
            current = batch_idx * len(X_batch)
            print(f"loss: {loss_value:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{len(dataset):>5d}]")

